# Error with Starting EOS on Docker

Tags: nodeos, docker

I am struggling to get EOS running on docker.

I have built the docker image but when I try to run it (`docker compose up`) I get these errors:

```
nodeosd_1  | 3156341ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2797           plugin_initialize    ] Initialize net plugin
nodeosd_1  | 3156341ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2818           plugin_initialize    ] host: 0.0.0.0 port: 9876 
nodeosd_1  | 3156342ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2890           plugin_initialize    ] my node_id is cafb1adad3ba7358bbc8a7cfafa6fc4537a9dafffc39fdb28af092eeb39192e1
nodeosd_1  | 3156342ms thread-0   main.cpp:91                   main                 ] nodeos version 19227c9b
nodeosd_1  | 3156342ms thread-0   main.cpp:92                   main                 ] eosio root is /root/.local/share
nodeosd_1  | 3156342ms thread-0   block_log.cpp:120             open                 ] Log is nonempty
nodeosd_1  | 3156343ms thread-0   block_log.cpp:128             open                 ] Index is nonempty
nodeosd_1  | 3156383ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:225          plugin_startup       ] 13 N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEEEE: content of memory does not match data expected by executable
nodeosd_1  | rethrow content of memory does not match data expected by executable: 
nodeosd_1  |     {"my->genesis_file.generic_string()":"/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir/genesis.json","what":"content of memory does not match data expected by executable"}
nodeosd_1  |     thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:225 plugin_startup
nodeosd_1  | 3156383ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:225          plugin_startup       ] my->genesis_file.generic_string(): /opt/eosio/bin/data-dir/genesis.json 
nodeosd_1  | 3156383ms thread-0   main.cpp:96                   main                 ] 13 N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEEEE: content of memory does not match data expected by executable
nodeosd_1  | rethrow content of memory does not match data expected by executable: 
nodeosd_1  |     {"my->genesis_file.generic_string()":"/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir/genesis.json","what":"content of memory does not match data expected by executable"}
nodeosd_1  |     thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:225 plugin_startup
docker_builder_1 exited with code 0
docker_nodeosd_1 exited with code 0
```

When I then run  `cleos get info` I get the following error:

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/eos/bin/cleos\": stat /opt/eos/bin/cleos: no such file or directory": unknown`

I will appreciate any pointers on this

## Update

I was using an old repo and have deleted it and pulled `master`.

When I try to run `docker build . -t eosio/eos`

I get this error now:

`[521/1334] Building CXX object libraries/chain/CMakeFiles/eosio_chain.dir/asset.cpp.o
The command '/bin/sh -c git clone -b $branch https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git --recursive     && cd eos && echo "$branch:$(git rev-parse HEAD)" > /etc/eosio-version     && cmake -H. -B"/tmp/build" -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWASM_ROOT=/opt/wasm -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/build  -DSecp256k1_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local -DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true -DCORE_SYMBOL_NAME=$symbol     && cmake --build /tmp/build --target install && rm /tmp/build/bin/eosiocpp' returned a non-zero code: 137`

Comment: 1. do you have clean repository?
2. on which tag/branch/commit you are?

Comment: Realised I was using an old repo and downloaded the master branch . New error with both the local install and th docker will update question. Which branch should I be on?

Comment: @noisy I have updated my question to show my  latest error

Comment: The first error looked like something went wrong with your genesis.json this might be some kind of docker volume misconfiguration

Comment: Regarding the second: did you try to pull the latest image from docker hub instead of building it on your own?

Comment: thanks @TeeAttack42. can you please provide steps to pulling from docker hub? I had assumed that following the instructs would build it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to pull the image from Docker Hub:

https://hub.docker.com/r/eosio/eos/

If you have correctly installed docker

```
sudo docker pull eosio/eos
```

Should be enough...

Be sure to maintain your images so that you don't try to start your local built image.

---

EDIT

From the [Quickstart Guide](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart).

If you want to start it use:

```
sudo docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -v /tmp/work:/work -v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data -v /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config eosio/eos-dev  /bin/bash -c "nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::wallet_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console"
```

Comment: Thanks when I pull this what command do I use to run it? Does it have to be in the eos git directory or can do I not need to download the whole git folder?